# The onChanges isn't fired when updating the content of a bound object

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-directive

I have parent child relationship in component. If I update value bound object in parent component then it has to notify in child component.

**ChildComponent**

```js
export class childComponent implements OnChanges {
@Input() data = { name: "Datta" };

ngOnChanges() {
  console.log('updated');
}
```

**ParentComponent.html**

```html
<child-com [data]="localData"></child-com>
<button (click)="buttonClick()">changeData</button>
```

**ParentComponent**

```js
 export class ParentComponent  {
localData: any;

buttonClick() {
  this.localData.name = "sagar";
}
```

If I change the reference of bound object then it will reflect but if I update the specific value in the object then it is not reflected.

Comment: Can you share complete code of parent, child component and view files?

Answer (score 5):

This is how Angular's change detection works. If the object reference doesn't change then the bound child component will not have its `onChanges` method called. You will need to update the reference. Example:

```js
this.localData = {
  ...this.localData,
  name: "sagar",
}
```

Comment: Is there any other way to get the change in child component without changing reference.?

Comment: No. Change detection is efficient because it relies on the fact that the object reference has or has not changed. It doesn't need to traverse the entire object to see if a property has changed.

Answer (score 0):

As per me, this line need to change.

```
@Input() data = { name: "Datta" };
```

to this:

```
  @Input() data;
```

Because here you are changing the reference of object.

If you need a name change in data object in child component, then call it inside ngOnInit like below:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.data.name = "Datta";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a typical problem statement in angular. Use Getter/Setter for property bindings and the changes can be detected in setter method.

```
export class childComponent {

  data: any = { name: "Datta" };

  get name(): any {
    return this.data;
  }

  @Input("data")
  set name(name: any) {
    this.data = name;
  }

}
```

Let me know, if this works.

Comment: thanks KunalMZ ..... my scenario is little bit difference, I am displaying value in child component on the basis of some filtration. So I want event once value is updated. As per my knowledge "set" function is called when actual object is changed or we can say reference is changed. so getter and setter  will not work in my case.